# Use of "make someone able to XXX"

Tags: grammar, construction

I have some doubts about the construction of this sentence:

> I want to make you able to play.

In my language this is a common construction. Is it a valid sentence in English too?

This is the form: **subject** + **to make** + **pronoun** + **able to verb**.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this construct. What makes you think otherwise?

Comment: @Irene This sentence sounded strange... so I've asked to be sure that its construction is correct and used in spoken English. 
Please add an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to make you **able to play**

is grammatical. If it confuses you, just compare with the shorter sentence

> I want to make you **happy**.

*Happy* is an adjective and *able to play* is an adjectival phrase.

Comment: And just to add to it: Compare `Will you be happy?` and `Will you be able to play?`.

Answer (score 5):

The sentence is grammatically correct, but it reads as awkward.

I think the main 'culprit' here is the words *be able* following the word *make*.

When we hear someone say:

> *I will make you*... (or, *I want to make you...*)

our minds might interpret *make* as forcing someone us to do something:

> *I will make you eat your vegatables before you can have any desert*.
>   *I will make you do your homework – whether you want to or not*.
>   *I want to make you join the choir this year. (You should have joined last year!)*

Secondarily, *able to play* is vague.  How do we *make* someone *able to play*? Boost their self-confidence? Provide physical therapy? Sign a permission form? Tape an ankle?

Combine those two, and we get a sentence that's perfectly grammatical, but still a little hard to piece together:

> *I want to make you able to play*.

Some alternatives (depending on what meaning you are trying to convey):

> *I want to help you be ready to play*.
>   *I want make sure you are able to play.*
>   *This medicine will make you able to play.*

Your original sentence construction is fine, but some word combinations simply don't fit well into certain constructs.

Answer (score 4):

If that sentence sounds odd to you, you could try:

*I want to enable you to play.*

[Enable](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/enable) has a definition of "make able."