# Is the sentence "That guy will make fall in love all those girls" correct?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, semantics

Is the sentence "That guy will make fall in love all those girls" correct, like "all those girls will fall in love with that guy", can I rewrite it like above?

Thanks for the attention!

Comment: "That guy will make all those girls fall in love (with him)" would be my suggestion.

Comment: related:[Is the phrase “I will infatuate you” correct?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/266078/is-the-phrase-i-will-infatuate-you-correct) and http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/95031/usage-of-infinitives-in-this-sentence/95032#95032 and [Use of “make someone able to XXX”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/70847/use-of-make-someone-able-to-xxx)

Answer (score 5):

We would say:

**That guy will make all those girls fall in love with him.**

If we leave out "with him", he could simply be a sort of love deity who makes people fall in love with each other.

With respect to "make"; notice how "him" comes between "make" and the complement "shake in his boots":

**The approaching tiger made him shake in his boots.**

We do not say "The approaching tiger made shake in his boots him".

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is understandable but it is rather bad English. If I were given it to edit, I would change it to "That guy would make all those girls fall in love", or I would prefer your second version.